# Create Button in last page pagination codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, button, pagination

Hello there I have problem

I wanna create button in my pagination codeIgniter **just in last page** for *submit form*

here my code:

Controller:

```
    function index() {
/* pagination config */
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('dcm/index');
        $config['per_page'] = 6;
        $config['num_link'] = 5;
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev' ;
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('soal')->num_rows();

/* this my form still have problem but I have different post for this one */
/* if you have any Idea for this please check my Question */
        $data['form_action'] = site_url('dcm/index');     
        $jawab = $this->input->post('jawab');
        $id_soal = $this->input->post('id_soal');
        $this->dcm_model->inputJawab();
        /*  */


/* pagination setting */
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['query'] = $this->db->get('soal', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
        $data['link'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('dcm/soal', $data);
}
```

in view:

```
<form action="<?php echo $form_action; ?>">
<?php  foreach($query->result() as $row) { ?>
<?php echo $row->id_soal . '. ' . $row->soal; ?>
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"  value="<?=$row->id_soal;?>" name="jawab[]" />
<?php } ?>
<?php echo $link; ?>
</form>
<input align="center" type="submit" value="selesai" />
```

Comment: what do you mean by that?! would you please explain more?!

Comment: I mean, I JUST want to create BUTTON for submit in LAST PAGE in my pagination, how to do it?? am I clear? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if you are on the last page with this code:

```
if($this->pagination->cur_page >= 
    ceil($this->pagination->total_rows / $this->pagination->per_page))
{
    $isLastPage = true;
}
else
{
    $isLastPage = false;
}
```

You can pass the `$isLastPage` variable to your view.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I need little more explanation. I have used it, I put after $isLastPage = true; $data['button'] = form_submit('Kirim', 'Sending post'); but it hasn't change anything?? why??

Comment: I GOT THIS! thank you, thanks FOR HELP, I am still newbie programmer thanks a lot for your help! :-)